# Texbox custom representation for Symfony2 entity form type?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

My entity `Person` has a one to many relation with `Tag` entity. When creating a new person i'd like to show a textbox for assigning **tag names separated by commas**. User can then input an existent tag name or a new tag name (in this case, a new `Tag` entity is created and persisted).

Unfortunately [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) has only checkbox and select representation. How can implement my own textbox representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom form type along with a custom data transformer.

[This article](http://readthedocs.org/docs/symfony2-document/en/latest/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) is a pretty good guide on creating your own form type.

Also, check out [Symfony's own source for the EntityType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php) to get an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be creating a custom [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).